# Invalid Handle (Using the Application Verifier)

Tags: c++, winapi, exception, 64-bit, handle

I have a problem I just can't find information for. The following code is causing the issue (I have left out a lot of code for brevity, but as I will explain, this code seems to work fine):

```
mHDC = GetDC(mHWnd);
int format = ChoosePixelFormat(mHDC, &pixelFormat);
SetPixelFormat(mHDC, format, &pixelFormat);
mHGLRC = wglCreateContext(mHDC);
wglMakeCurrent(mHDC, mHGLRC);
```

`mHWnd` is obtained through `CreateWindow()`

```
const HINSTANCE hInstance(static_cast<HINSTANCE>(::GetModuleHandle(NULL)));

mHWnd = CreateWindow(wndClass.lpszClassName, L"Test Application", style, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, clientRect.right, clientRect.bottom, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

`ChoosePixelFormat()` is causing an invalid handle first-chance exception in the debugger when I am using the Application Verifier with only Handles and Cuzz enabled. These two together cause the exception to trigger. Without both of these enabled (even if I just do one or the other), the exception isn't thrown and everything works okay. When I run the application without attaching to the debugger, the application crashes instead.

Even though the exception is raised, once I hit `wglMakeCurrent()` (by continuing debugging after and ignoring the exception), all the variables seem to end up with valid values anyway:

```
mHWnd == 0x1a1064e
mHDC == 0x440119c0
format == 7
mHGLRC == 0x10000
```

The stack trace looks like this:

```
ntdll.dll!00000000772012f7()
vfbasics.dll!000007feedaa81b4()
KernelBase.dll!000007fefd1610dc()
vfbasics.dll!000007feedaa7ce9()
vfcuzz.dll!000007fee5075179()
nvoglv64.dll!000000006979b732()
vfbasics.dll!000007feedaac1d5()
kernel32.dll!0000000076fa652d()
ntdll.dll!00000000771dc521()
```

And the active thread is a `vfcuzz.dll` thread, which is obviously allowing Cuzz to do it's business. `vfbasics.dll` in the stack trace is where the handle checker is, and as I said, only the handle checker is enabled.

For completion sake, here is the actual exception message:

```
First-chance exception at 0x00000000772012F7 (ntdll.dll) in Tests.exe: 0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified.
```

I am assuming it isn't a bug in the Application Verifier that is causing it to throw an exception that shouldn't exist and crashing the program. I am just confused as to why it is throwing the exception when clearly I am getting valid values back from the function calls. I don't really want to ignore it until I understand what is going on.

Comment: About all you can do is update your NVidia video driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like a problem with your code. The only handle `ChoosePixelFormat` takes is an `HDC` and the one you're giving it is presumably valid (although in the code you're showing there's no checking that `GetDC` succeeded, I assume you just left that out for brevity).

A first-chance exception isn't necessarily a problem. It simply means an exception occurred, and this is the first chance to handle it. My guess is the exception is most likely happening within the `ChoosePixelFormat` function itself (or within a function that `ChoosePixelFormat` calls) and being handled there - it's only because you are debugging that you actually find out about it. In every day usage the exception would be handled quietly and you'd never even know it had happened.

Comment: So I guess the Application Verifier is detecting the exception before ChoosePixelFormat() has a chance to handle it's exception. That makes sense, I'll ignore it until someone sheds different light on the matter.

Comment: Exactly. For example, with the VS debugger, you can configure it to stop on first-chance exceptions. This lets you catch and examine exceptions before the application itself has a chance to handle them. If you don't stop on them in a debugger they go back to the app, which often will handle them just fine - it's only if the app doesn't handle the first-chance exception that you get a second-chance exception which then leads to a crash if nothing catches it.